# How to change the size of the below box using CSS?

Tags: html, css

My quantity box is out of alignment.

**Out of alignment**
[image]

It was supposed to look like the follow under the `Quantity` label

**Correct alignment**
[image]

Everything I tried doesn't work. What would be the best CSS code for this?

Code I tried:

```
width:100%
margin-width: 450px
```

Expecting the box to look like this under the Quantity field:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet so that can know the actual issue.

Comment: "**The answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything is 42.**" - 
Without code, we cannot see the error. Please provide a code snippet that can minimally reproduce the error shared in the images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By giving position relative to main div and absolute to the drop-down div you can set the layout as shone in the image.

```css
.main-div{
            width:90%;
            height: 150px;
            position: relative;
            border: solid black 2px;
        }
        .dropdown-div{
            position: absolute;
            top: 25%;
            right: 10%;;
            border: solid black 2px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
        Text Here
        <div class="dropdown-div">
            <p>dropdown-content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi , this is the snippet I think you need.

Comment: <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tblBasketQty">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td style="height: 15px; width: 20px; vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                                                <span id="ctl00_cphMainPage_gvSC_ctl02_lblQuantity">1</span>
               </td> <td align="center" style="width: 20px;">
                            <div id="ctl00_cphMainPage_gvSC_ctl02_panel2" class="divQTYButtons" style="height:30px;width:15px;">

Comment: Please provide more it seems to be incomplete

Comment: can you add an attachment here?

the rest of the code has too many characters.